# What causes the Total # of Contentions to drop to 0?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm investigating a C# program that has thread contention issues. I'm monitoring the app in Windows Performance Monitor, and one of the things being monitoring is the "Total # of Contentions". Naturally, since it's a total number it climbs as the application runs.

The curious thing is that sometimes the number suddenly drops to 0, and then continues to climb normally. When this happens the program wasn't stopped and restarted, it continued to run the entire time.

So what can cause the total # of contentions to drop to 0? Does garbage collection do that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Simplest explanation is that it just overflowed.  It is a 32-bit counter so after 2^32 ~= 4 billion it will go back to 0.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I don't think that's it. In one case I just looked at it got up to 7896, then dropped to 0.